# Ember model rollback reset the view to previous state

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data

I've got a simple form (that container a few textfields and checkboxes bound to the model) which is either visible or hidden using jQuery's slideToggle.

This form has two buttons: Save and Cancel.

Basically this form becomes visible when I need to make some changes to the model. When save button is clicked I save the model

```
this.get('model.content').save();
```

and hide the form.

Same goes for the cancel. I tried calling

```
this.get('model.content').rollback();
```

but it does not reverts the textfields, nor resets the checkboxes. I'd like them to be in previous 'unsaved' state when I open the form next time. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rollback the model:

```
this.get('model').rollback();
```

However, relying on the user to click "Cancel" might be a problem-  What if they navigate using the back button?  In my experience, it's better to bind your forms to a copy of the model object, so you can easily throw away changes.  The "save" action will copy from the temporary object back to the route's model and save.  Also, consider the implications of the server failing to save.  You should probably have a `then()` on your call to `save()` so you can warn the user / recover / rollback / etc.

You can copy each attribute to a "buffer" attribute and in your form template do this:

```
{{#with buffer}}
    {{input value=fieldOne}}
    {{input value=fieldTwo}}
{{/with}}
```

To create an `attributes` computed property on your model object, add this:

```
attributes: function() {
    var model = this,
        result = [];
    Ember.keys(this.get('data')).forEach(function(key) {
        result.push(Ember.Object.create({
            model: model,
            key: key,
            valueBinding: 'model.' + key
        }));
    });
    return result;
}.property()
```

Then, to create a temporary buffer for your form to use, you can do this on your controller:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    var buffer={};
    controller.set('model', model);
    model.get('attributes').forEach(function(item) {
        buffer[item.get('key')]= item.get('value');
    });
    controller.set('buffer', buffer);
    this._super(controller, model);
}
```

I personally use these as `Mixin`s, so I can easily add them to all my model objects and edit controllers.

Comment: Thanks Steve! How do I use the buffer? When I put it around my form like this it just hides the content. How I need to do something in the controller? Also model still does nothing. Do I need to commit the changes to the model in order for it to work. Mind you when I click "Cancel" nothing is "saved" or set on the model, so probably the model doesn't know what to rollback to? The I click save I just want the changes to the way there before someone typed something in.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more code you can use.

Comment: @SteveH. Would it be easier to check if the model is in a dirty state when you need to access it and then roll it back if it is?

Comment: @Chachi-inactive In my opinion, it is easier to simply toss the buffer when you don't need it and then recreate upon re-entry to the route.  You could try it that way as an optimization.

Comment: @SteveH. - so what I've concluded is that the rollback method is super convenient until you use a custom transform with ember-data. `rollback()` doesn't know how to deal with custom data, so it doesn't actually roll it back.

Comment: @Chachi-inactive, if the property is a plain object, it should revert to its original value, assuming it is defined in the model as `DS.attr()`.

Comment: @SteveH. - so it doesn't rollback for an array defined as `DS.attr()` I had to do something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344574/ember-data-model-rollback-not-working-on-custom-attribute-of-model) because the change isn't detected. I guess technically the property isn't changing though.

Comment: @Chachi-inactive Oh, I see- yes, you are simply modifying elements in the array and not replacing the array completely.  In that case, yes, you are correct, Ember will not trigger a change because it's still the same array!

Answer (score 2):

In your Ember 2.10 component, add:

```
  willDestroyElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('model').rollbackAttributes();
  }
```

This will reset your model's unsaved changes right before your form component is removed from the DOM. This is especially useful when users leave your form without saving. You will then want to prevent the changes made from propagating through your app. This assumes you pass model properties into your input fields like so:

```
 {{input value=model.name}}
```

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_rollback
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#method_willDestroy

Comment: Instead of `willDestroy` method, override `willDestroyElement` event hook method, `willDestroyElement(){ this._super(...arguments); //your tear down step }` .thats what they suggested in [ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/) . but any how both should work.

Comment: @kumkanillam You are absolutely right. Thanks for pointing that out.