# Ember Data Model rollback not working on custom attribute of model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this JS bin. Does anyone know the reason why, when I modify the user model and click the button to rollback, why the firstName property is being rolled back but not the array custom attribute? Thanks.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nunihuco/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ember Data watches the property itself.  The property itself isn't changing, your data inside is.  You'd need to change the property for it to be able to `rollback`.

```
this.set('model.listOfStuff', ['hello','world']);
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nunihuco/2/edit

If you wanted, you could clone and modify.  This only works on primitive types though, if you have objects, you'd run into the same thing.

```
  var orig = this.get('listOfStuff'),
      newArr = orig.slice();
  this.set('listOfStuff', newArr);
  newArr[0] = 'asdf';
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nunihuco/3/edit

Comment: Ah, I get it, thanks. So what would be a workaround for that? Is it a good idea to cache the previous value of the array anytime it changes, incase I want to do a rollback?

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to clone to be able to modify and still be able to rollback.  I tossed up a small example.